# Flash in android(not in webview)

Tags: android, flash

I am  writing android application and I don't use webview. I want to know can I insert flash object in my application,and if yes ,how can I do that.If you can write samples please.
Thanks

Comment: What do you care if it is displayed in webview?
webview is used just as a "player" for the flash file

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use AIR for Android SDK

Comment: can you write some example or some  link ?